# Why am I getting this error : "ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to read .csv file to import its contents to SQL table

I'm getting error:

```
ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.
```

at the last line of this code:

```
Function ImportData(ByVal FU As FileUpload, ByVal filename As String, ByVal tablename As String) As Boolean
Try

    Dim xConnStr As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};dbq=" & Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(filename)) & ";extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"

    ' create your excel connection object using the connection string
    Dim objXConn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(xConnStr.Trim())
    objXConn.Open()

    Dim objCommand As New OdbcCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM " & Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(filename)), objXConn))

    If objXConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        objXConn.Open()
    Else
        objXConn.Close()
        objXConn.Open()
    End If

    ' create a DataReader
    Dim dr As OdbcDataReader
    dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: why did you have several `conn.Open()`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is as follow:

```
Dim xConnStr As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};dbq=" & Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(filename)) & ";extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;" 

    ' create your excel connection object using the connection string 
    Dim objXConn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(xConnStr.Trim()) 

    Dim objCommand As New OdbcCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM " & Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(filename)), objXConn)) 

    objCommand.Connection.Open()


    ' create a DataReader 
    Dim dr As OdbcDataReader 
    dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

The connection is passed to the command but the command needs to open the connection as  shown above with the line `objCommand.Connection.Open()` 
thus **removing** the intial `objXconn.Open()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't use your OdbcConnection to [create the command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.createcommand.aspx) you'll need to set the [Connection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.connection.aspx) on the command before you execute it:

```
objCommand.Connection = objXConn
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've closed it before calling ExecuteReader.

```
//this line has rightly assign the connection to the command
Dim objCommand As New OdbcCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM " & Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(filename)), objXConn))
```

but the connection has to be in the Open state. You might have closed it somehow here

```
If objXConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    objXConn.Open()
Else
    objXConn.Close()
    objXConn.Open()
End If
```